# Eliminar el problema de java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, archivo, impresión, split

Lo que intento realizar en este programa es pasar un archivo que contiene una serie de tablas como si fuera un excel y acomodar los datos en el codigo de forma que se impriman los datos de la misma forma en la con java.lang.NullPointerException que me sale al final de mi impresion, no se realmente a que se deba asi que quisiera que me pudieran ayuda por favor. Segun el programa mi error esta en la linea 25.

```
    try {
        String[] data = new String[47];
        String lineaTemporal;
        File archivo = new File("Mat.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String linea;

        for (int i = 0; i < 47; i++) {
            data[i] = br.readLine();
            lineaTemporal = data[i];
            String[] parts = lineaTemporal.split(" ");
            for (String part1 : parts) {
                System.out.print(part1);
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        //while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //    System.out.println(linea);
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Deberías indicar en que linea te esta saltando el error. De todas formas tal como tienes el programa estas obligando a que el archivo de texto tenga 47 líneas. No deberías leer los datos con un for, sino con un while que pare cuando no encuentre mas líneas que leer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con este codigo:

```
try {
        String[] data = new String[47];
        String lineaTemporal;
        File archivo = new File("Mat.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String linea;
        long i = 0;

        while ((sCadena = br.readLine())!=null) {
            data[i] = br.readLine();
            lineaTemporal = data[i];
            String[] parts = lineaTemporal.split(" ");
            for (String part1 : parts) {
                System.out.print(part1);
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            i++;
        }

        //while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //    System.out.println(linea);
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
      fnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe){
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

De esta forma solo vas a llenar la cantidad de lineas que tenga el archivo, debes tener cuidado porque si el fichero tiene mas de 47 lineas se rompe el arreglo.

Comment: Gracias amigo esa era la respuesta, mi archivo tenia solamente 36 lineas por lo que el resto de las lineas eran nulas asi que eso me hacia que me saltara el error, gracias por el consejo y la respuesta :D

Comment: De nada, ten cuidado con el caso en que el arreglo sea de menor tamaño a la de la cantidad de lineas del fichero